# MySQL select rand and exclude users with condition

Tags: mysql

I need to select random `user_id` from "user" table, and completely exclude any `user_id` if current user have any "ongoing" battles with him `battles.status`

**Query:**

```
SELECT user.id
FROM user
LEFT JOIN battles b ON b.uid = user.id AND b.status <>  'ongoing'
WHERE user.id <> 1
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 1
```

But the query is not sufficient, because a user can have multiple battles with specific other users, one of them "ongoing" and the others "finished",
My query should select users from the "finished" row.

Tables structure:

**user** table:

```
id    name
1      John
2      Sarah
3      Jack
4      Andy
5      Rio
```

**battles** table:

```
id      uid      uid2      status
1        1         2       finished
2        1         2       ongoing
3        2         3       ongoing
4        1         4       finished
5        3         5       finished
```

If "my" id = "1",
I want to completely exclude any user I have ongoing battle with him, like "2" in the above case and accept all other ids (i.e.3,4 and 5)

Comment: This is actually why scriptlanguages are so common nowadays, sure you can write a function which returns you a randomnumber and include this in your select statement, but why would you want to do that inside a query? This is a 2fingertask when writing it in PHP or any other Scriptlanguage

Comment: I want to do it only in MySQL, if it possible

Comment: Sure it is possible, but the question you should ask is "why am i doing this" mostly you need such solitions when not thinking about throughout. 
Also in your example you got one finished an one ongoing battle with the same users, this also indicates that something went wrong there. If i get your question right you only need to exclude all users which have the users ID as uid2

Comment: I need it to be in MySQL to increase performance

Comment: You won't increase performance by writing your gamelogic in mysql.

Comment: Open one connection with mysql and return expected data ,That no need to extra processing, Increase performance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT foe.*

-- Select yourself and join all other users to find potential foes
FROM `user` AS me
INNER JOIN `user` AS foe
  ON (me.id <> foe.id)

-- Here we select the active user
WHERE me.`id` = 1

-- Now we exclude foes we have ongoing battles with
--    (your id could be in either uid or uid2)
AND foe.`id` NOT IN (
    SELECT `uid`  FROM `battles`
    WHERE `uid2` = me.`id` AND `status` = 'ongoing'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT `uid2` FROM `battles`
    WHERE `uid`  = me.`id` AND `status` = 'ongoing'
);
```

This will return a list of users which you do not currently have ongoing battles with.  You can customise this to return just one of them using LIMIT and random ordering like in your example.

Comment: I need to return only "1" random user.id

Comment: @mwafi You can easily implement that bit yourself exactly the same way you did before (swap `foe.*` to `foe.\`id\`` and add the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses). I'm just showing you a reliable way of finding opponents.

Comment: And this will also not increase your performance, as you have to run multiple queries with filtering in order to get to your data

Comment: @mwafi just use `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;`